# What function should I use in tbl_regression to tidy (argument tidy_fun) lm output performed on grouped data?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I just discovered the package gtsummary and I am like wow, I want to get this type of fast table for my linear regression, but I have some troubles to make it work for me.
I have a data table containing growth and fluorescence data. The data are grouped by experimental condition fluorescence type. I did a linear regression on this data see exemple bellow

```
#make a dummy data table 

d <- data.frame(
      condition = rep(c('B', 'U'), 20),
      growth = rep(1:20, 2),
type=rep(c(F1,F2,F3,F4),5)
      response= rnorm(20)
    )
#run lm on grouped data by condition and fluorescence type 
linear_models <- d%>%
  group_by(type,condition)%>%
  do(model = lm(growth ~fluo, data = .))
#make table with tbl_regression 
tbl_regression(linear_models)
```

here I get an error message telling me that the tidy function failed to tidy the model

```
! `broom::tidy()` failed to tidy the model.
x Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm)
! `tidy_parameters()` also failed.
! `broom::tidy()` failed to tidy the model.
x Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm)
! `tidy_parameters()` also failed.
x There was an error calling `tidy_fun()`. Most likely, this is because the
function supplied in `tidy_fun=` was misspelled, does not exist, is not
compatible with your object, or was missing necessary arguments (e.g. `conf.level=` or `conf.int=`). See error message below.
Error: Error in eval(expr, envir = list(`?` = function(...) stop()), enclos = envir): You need to install 'parameters' to use 'tidy_parameters'.
In addition: There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I tried to get a table using broom::tidy directly, it works but it is not he table I want to get.

```
linear_models <- d%>%
  group_by(type,condition)%>%
  do(broom::tidy(lm(growth ~fluo, .)))
```

Can anyone please hint toward what I missed in tbl_regression function and how to make work on my model?

Sorry for being long! thanks

Comment: there is no `fluo` column in the input example

Comment: sorry my bad, I mad a mistake in col names while creating my dummy data, fluo should be response

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `map` to loop over the 'model' object in the `list` and apply the `tbl_regession

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
out <- d%>%
  group_by(type,condition)%>%
  do(model = lm(growth ~response, data = .)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(model = map(model, tbl_regression))
```

-checking

```
out$model[[2]]
```

[image]

---

Or another option is to apply the `tbl_regression` directly on the `lm` within `summarise` and return as a `list` object

```
out <- d %>%
  group_by(type, condition) %>%
  summarise(model = list(tbl_regression(lm(growth ~ response))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  type  condition model     
  <chr> <chr>     <list>    
1 F1    B         <tbl_rgrs>
2 F2    U         <tbl_rgrs>
3 F3    B         <tbl_rgrs>
4 F4    U         <tbl_rgrs>
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(condition = c("B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", 
"U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", 
"B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", 
"U", "B", "U", "B", "U", "B", "U"), growth = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), type = c("F1", "F2", 
"F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", 
"F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", 
"F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", 
"F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"), response = c(0.513847456201564, 
-0.820367660407753, 0.440731787146136, 0.203848762708769, -0.529724800374613, 
-1.43570130262853, 0.0732862795002955, -0.740805987248482, -0.603335474342407, 
-0.41537077313497, 0.457044030941835, -2.16121669238704, 0.423012730497808, 
-0.302949652630124, -0.0691136349178037, 0.0709372889906787, 
1.20684795477784, 0.182525811801302, 0.195440636740125, -0.348940594898786, 
0.513847456201564, -0.820367660407753, 0.440731787146136, 0.203848762708769, 
-0.529724800374613, -1.43570130262853, 0.0732862795002955, -0.740805987248482, 
-0.603335474342407, -0.41537077313497, 0.457044030941835, -2.16121669238704, 
0.423012730497808, -0.302949652630124, -0.0691136349178037, 0.0709372889906787, 
1.20684795477784, 0.182525811801302, 0.195440636740125, -0.348940594898786
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```